# Angular 8 not building with ng2-adsense

Tags: angular, angular8, adsense

Im using the Google Adsense lib `ng2-adsense` for `Angular` apps to show my ads.

I followed the steps found here: https://github.com/scttcper/ng2-adsense/

1. Add the `adsbygoogle.js` script to the head.
2. Add `AdsenseModule` to `NgModule` imports array.
3. Add `<ng-adsense>` tag to my app.component.html file where i want the ad to show.

It works ok locally (no critical errors are shown when i run `ng run serve`).

When I attempt to build my angular app for distribution to Firebase I get the following error.

> ng build --prod

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-adsense/fesm5/ng2-adsense.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (/Users/.../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:265:35)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a permanent solution but I temporarily fixed the production build by changing `buildOptimizer` to `false` in the `angular.json` file.

```
                "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": false,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
```